# I'm getting error in pl/sql. can anyone help me?

Tags: mysql

why getting this error?
getting error like check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE p_dept()
    -> DECLARE
    -> p_ename varchar(15);
    -> CURSOR cl IS select e_name from employee
    -> where e_salary=60000;
    -> BEGIN
    -> OPEN cl;
    -> FETCH cl into p_ename;
    -> dbms_output.put_line(p_ename);
    -> close cl;
    -> end;//
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE
> p_ename varchar(15);
> CURSOR cl IS select e_name from employee
> where e_sa' at line 2

Comment: Ermmm, MySQL in nothing to do with PLSQL, which is used with Oracle

Comment: I think you just need to read the MySQL Manual RE: Stored Proceedure syntax

Comment: BEGIN-END is lost. Either add a block or move `BEGIN` from line 6 to line 2.

Comment: *`dbms_output.put_line`* cannot be used in MySQL.